# Получение материалов поста vkontakte с помощью attachments

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как извлечь из поста все вложенные материалы (фото, видео, аудиозаписи) по средствам `attachments`?

Запрос:

```
VKParameters params = new VKParameters();
params.put("posts", linkPost);
params.put(VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1);
postRequest = new VKRequest("wall.getById", params);
```

Не могу разобраться, как обращаться к полям массива `attachments`

```
VKList posts = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);
```

Ошибка приходится на последнюю строку.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена путем парсинга json, который пришел в ответ на запрос. В приведенном фрагменте извлекается ссылка на фотографию поста.

```
try {
    JSONArray items = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) response.json).get("response")).getJSONArray("items");
    JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(0);
    JSONArray att = (JSONArray) item.getJSONArray("attachments");
    JSONObject xx = (JSONObject) att.get(0);
    img = xx.getJSONObject("photo").getString("photo_604");
    Log.d("MSCurrentPost", "JSON: " + img);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение простое, попробуй переписать без использования библиотек, напрямую обращаясь к API, например, через Asynchttpclient, так нагляднее и быстрее. Так же напиши, пожалуйста, название либы, через которую ты берешь посты.